# Missing Return Statement Using Script Bool

Tags: return, runtime-error

My code is throwing a "Missing return statement" but I'm not savvy enough to fully understand why. Here's the code:

```
script bool FindStr(Array<string> aArray, string aKey)
    foreach (string key in aArray)
    {
        if (key == aKey)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
end_script
```

Running the code provides the error statement, and the end_script line is pointed out as being the problem.

Comment: Because if you get all the way through the loop, then there is no return statement.  You need `return false;` after the loop.

Comment: Not all paths return

Comment: I imagine it's because of what happens when `key == aKey` isn't true...